# Official hosted image assets for social media networks

Tags: facebook, twitter, cdn

It seems wrong that I should have to host copies of image assets that I want to use on my site. I refuse to copy over or cut up another Facebook icon again.

Do the big social media sites have a static URL that I can use on my site to load their logos? Alternatively, are there any third party CDNs that host social media logos and assets (I'm thinking something like Google's CDN for JavaScript libraries.. only for social media icons)?

The thing I want to avoid is just scraping the logo from Facebook's HTML or AddThis' servers and have them change it a month or 12 down the road.

Practically speaking, I would be fine with just Facebook and Twitter logos, but maybe other people out there would like some more networks.

Comment: that's your average startup idea right there

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebookbrand.com/

"Find Facebook logos, images, 
product names and screenshots, 
and other assets and learn how 
to use them"

Still have to download, but its the closest you'll probably get.

OR

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button